# What was the impact of Impagliazzo's A Personal View of Average Case Complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, history

I'm studying [his paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/514853) and I was wondering how the community reacted to it. Yes, Average Case Complexity has come a long way since then, but I want to know if it was directly influenced by it.

Comment: Seems more appropriate for [cstheory.se], but it's hard to predict whether they will like it. If you ask it there, please remove it here to prevent duplicates. (You could then re-ask it here if they say it's not appropriate there.)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, that's exactly what happened, they closed the question as being off-topic, that's why I asked it here.